# How do I know if I have a gem on my local machine?

Tags: ruby, unix, rubygems

I have the Rails gem and the data_mapper gem installed on my local machine (macbook). When I am in my terminal, I can type `which rails` and it give me a directory like `/Users/andyhuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rails`.

However, if I type `which data_mapper`, I get `data_mapper not found`. How am I able to figure out what gems I have installed on my local machine? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: This only work for Rails, Bundler, and other gems that install a binary link. This will include any gem whose source contains a `/bin` dir in its root.

Comment: Great to know! My question has been answered. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I know if I have a gem on my local machine?

Type `gem list`.

Comment: or more specifically `gem list data_mapper`

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for executable files with `which`. You can list all gems with `gems list` or `bundle list` if you are using bundler.

You can search for specific gem with `gem list | grep gemname` or `bundle show gemname`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using RVM or any other Ruby version manager, you might have it install in other Ruby version.

```
rvm list
```

will let you know which version you have installed and which one you are using. Check on other versions with:

```
rvm use 'ruby_version'
```

and then

```
gem list gemname
```